# Efficient pagination with MySQL

Tags: mysql, pagination

I'm trying to speed up pagination of data on my site. I'd like to use the following query, but when I do an EXPLAIN it says it needs to scan over 40,000 rows:

```
SELECT `Item`.`id`, `User`.`id` 
FROM `items` AS `Item` 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` 
    ON (`Item`.`submitter_id` = `User`.`id`) 
WHERE `Item`.`made_popular` < "2010-02-08 22:05:05" 
  AND `Item`.`removed` != 1 
ORDER BY `Item`.`made_popular` DESC 
LIMIT 26
```

But if I add a lower bound for the "made_popular" field it only needs to scan 99 rows (the number of items between those two dates).

```
SELECT `Item`.`id`, `User`.`id`
FROM `items` AS `Item` 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` 
    ON (`Item`.`submitter_id` = `User`.`id`) 
WHERE `Item`.`made_popular` < "2010-02-08 22:05:05" 
    AND `Item`.`made_popular` > "2010-02-07 22:05:05" 
    AND `Item`.`removed` != 1 
ORDER BY `Item`.`made_popular` DESC 
LIMIT 26
```

Both queries use the index I have on the "made_popular" column.
In both cases shouldn't it only need to scan 26 rows, assuming there are no "removed" items? I guess the solution could be to go with the second query and add a lower bound that is probably low enough to give me 26 items, but it seems odd that I should have to do a workaround like that.

Comment: LIMIT N,M allows you to set the offset (N) and number of results to return (M). Does LIMIT 1,26 improve performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
but when I do an EXPLAIN it says it needs to scan over 40,000 rows:
```

It is often to misunderstand what `rows` means. It means approximate amount of rows that could be used to return the result **regardless** `LIMIT` clause.

So you shouldn't worry in this case - mysql stops fetching data right after it reaches `LIMIT` amount.

Comment: Ok, so both these queries should perform exactly the same? Is there any way to find out the number of rows it needs to scan, taking the limit clause into consideration?

Comment: @makeee: yes. And make sure you have composite index `removed + made_popular`.

Comment: @makeee: "Is there any way to find out the number of rows it needs to scan, taking the limit clause into consideration" --- what engine type your tables are? If innodb - then there are some low-level tools that can show how many records actually were fetched from disk.

Comment: @zerkms so an index on made_popular,removed (removed being the second one)? What if less than 1% of rows are "removed"? Is it always worth adding this or is there a tradeoff somewhere, like increased index size? Thanks for the help.

Comment: `show status like '%innodb%';` -- this is how it can be done for innodb. Look at `Innodb_data_reads` value.

Comment: @makeee: index should be `removed + made_popular` where removed is in the first position. And doesn't matter that cardinality of `removed` is low - you're using composite index and only cardinality of pair of fields matters.

Comment: @zerkms if I were to add "removed" to the index, would it be possible to stick to my current pagination method of using LIMIT 12000,26 without the query having to scan the whole table from 0 - 12026? Or is that method always going to result in a full table scan?

Comment: @makeee: nope, mysql sucks on such long offsets and afaik there is no proper way to improve such queries. But, mysql will not perform - it will perform index scan (if there are proper indexes).